# Using LabVIEW for recording and playing sound (buffer size issue)

Tags: audio-streaming, audio-recording, labview

I have an analog to digital convertor (USB 6002) connected to a microphone. 
Is there an option in LabVIEW to record the sound and play it via the computer's speakers in real time ? 
I have tried to use the daq assistant VI and connected it to a play waveform VI but the sound is played with a delay and the program shuts down after a few seconds saying there is a problem with the buffer size.

is there an optimal sampling rate I should use? 
Should I use a continous sampling option or N samples option?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: Some delay is inevitable if you are converting audio to digital and back again - whether or not LabVIEW is involved - so how much delay can you accept?

Comment: Do you have your code?

Comment: Best result would require the use of a FPGA.